# ASP:GridView How to access value of a control set in <EditItemTemplate>

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview

In my Gridview when a user edits a row, I'm showing couple of asp:TextBox boxes using the EditItemTemplate.

One of the Text Box is bound to the UpdateParameters of my asp:ObjectDataSource.
However the Second Box is not bound to any of the update parameters.
I'm assigning a custom value to the second box.

Now my problem is, when the row is updated how do i read the value of my second text box??

I tried catching the value of the second text box in Grid_RowUpdating and  ObjectDataSource1_Updating but I'm unable to find the second control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

(GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("Textbox2") as TextBox).Text

Comment: Yeah I did, it does not work. Using FindControl i'm able to find the first text box but not second. The first text box is bound to the update parameter, while second one is not.